Raise one side of bench by 2mm
New to woodworking. I made side benching/window seat which is in two separate parts that will sit next to each other with the tops of each bench meeting. These tops should be flush with each other to give one continuous level bench. Obviously I built the second bench and found that the tops don't match exactly, they are level at the front but the second bench is 2mm lower at the back.
I've not fixed the top of the second bench on yet and am wondering if there's a neat way to raise the back of it so it is 2mm higher. My first thought is to get 2mm thick bit of wood from somewhere and attach it between the support and the top. Or maybe I should just attach the second bench top and then sand down the first bench so that it is level where they meet.
Is there a good way to do this?
Thanks



Are both of your tops level (in their current position as shown)? Do they need to be? Is your floor level? What does the bottom of the structure look like? It seems to me the easiest thing to do is to just shim the base of the table with a thin strip of wood.

I would definitely not recommend sanding as a solution to this problem, at least not to remove a difference of 2mm. It would be very difficult to maintain the sanded surface flat across its length (as opposed to just dishing out the part where the two tops meet). And of course it’s noisy and can make a mess.

P.S. I can’t quite figure out how your structure is made from the picture, but you might have something funky going on there with grain direction (in terms of wood movement).

"Or maybe I should just attach the second bench top and then sand down the first bench so that it is level where they meet." Just as a general FYI, that is an absolute ton of wood to remove by sanding (especially if using standard rotary or ROS sanders). That amount of material removal is totally viable by hand planing though, even if you only had a no. 4 with just one iron — 2mm is more than you'd really want to remove with a smoothing plane, but it is doable.


My first thought is to get 2mm thick bit of wood from somewhere and attach it between the support and the top.

Yes, this is called a shim and it's certainly a viable fix here.
Shims of various kinds are routinely used to level out things in built-in construction (e.g to account for uneven or non-level floors).
I think the ideal would be to lift the frame (i.e. the shimming goes on the floor) but there's no technical reason you can't shim under the seat on top of the framing.

You didn't ask about it but the slight discrepancy at the front edges can be dealt with by planing some material from the left panel. This will simultaneously get rid of the visible chipout/spelching visible in the second photo, so well worth taking the time if the front edges remain visible when the project is in service.

Spelching… I learned a word today.

Thanks, shim it is then, good to know from other comments that sanding is pretty much a no go.

For the front edge I was just gonna shift the top forward and leave a gap at the back which will usually be covered by a cushion eventually, but now you mention it I think I will plane it even
